# error for setting range for NSURLConnection, NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: iphone

I am trying to implement download resuming functionality by using 
setValue:forHTTPHeaderField.
But whenever I use that method, I get an

> [NSURLRequest setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x4e0b710 2011-08-08 22:44:36.469 Patch[9140:207] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURLRequest
>   setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x4e0b710'

error.

My code works fine without that method but when I include this code, I get the error above

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                     timeoutInterval:60.0];

//---------------- setting range for download resume -----------------------
NSString* range = @"bytes=";
range = [range stringByAppendingString:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:offset] stringValue]];
range = [range stringByAppendingString:@"-"];
NSLog(@"range: %@", range);

[request setValue:range forHTTPHeaderField:@"Range"];
```

please help me... Thank you very much

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create an `NSMutableURLRequest` with an `NSMutableURLRequest`.

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                     timeoutInterval:60.0];
```